# Facebook Audience Network Ads crashed as "divide by zero error" on Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, facebook, facebook-audience-network

I'm using Facebook Audience Network Ads in my Android game. It generally works fine but it sometimes(every time in the same ad) crashed and exiting my game. I attached the problem as a image from LogCat. What the problem is here, guys?

Logcat: https://snag.gy/tgWHvp.jpg

Comment: I also got the same Issue..https://www.facebook.com/help/audiencenetwork/community/question/?id=1599013493476632&added

Comment: I closed autoplay for ads, and there is no error now. The error show autoplay ads.